# Webpack and assets/dist folder

Tags: url, webpack, static, assets, angular5

I'm using Angular5 and webpack for generate the dist folder.
For generating the assets folder i'm using the "copy-webpack-plugin". It copies the assets folder from /src/assets into /dist folder.
The problem is: all the path used by a admin console template of my src code uses relative paths starting from "assets/..." and the server include /dist/assets. All static resources will throw 404 not found.
What is the best way to include an assets folder into a dist folder?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the [`file-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/#src/components/Sidebar/Sidebar.jsx) designed for this very purpose.

Once you have it configured in your `webpack.config.js` you can import paths to your files for use in JavaScript, as well as HTML templates if you're also using the [`html-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/).

```
const myImageUrl = require('./path/to/an/image.png')

doSomething(myImageUrl)
```